# Mixin for font-face isn't printing styles when used

Tags: css, sass, font-face, mixins

I have the following folder structure:

[image]

`style.scss` looks like this:

```html
@import "mixins.scss";
@import "theme/**.scss";
```

Everything from `style.scss` is compiled within `theme.min.css`.

In `_mixin.scss`, I have a mixin for `font-face`:

```html
@mixin font-face($font-name, $file-name, $weight: normal, $style: normal) {
  @font-face {
    font-family: quote($font-name);
    src: url($file-name + '.eot');
    src: url($file-name + '.eot?#iefix')  format('embedded-opentype'),
    url($file-name + '.otf') format('otf'),
    url($file-name + '.woff') format('woff'),
    url($file-name + '.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url($file-name + '.ttf')  format('truetype'),
    url($file-name + '.svg##{$font-name}')  format('svg');
    font-weight: $weight;
    font-style: $style;
    font-display: swap;
  }
}

@mixin lemonmilk-bold{
  @include font-face("lemonmilk", "/assets/build/fonts/lemon-milk/bold/lemonmilk-bold", $style: normal, $weight: normal);
}
```

And in `_typography.scss`, I have the following:

```css
h1{
  @include lemonmilk-bold;
}
```

However, the font styles do not apply on the front end?

I thought it was something to do with the folder path maybe (as all styles get compiled to `theme.min.css`). But, changing the paths did nothing for me too.

Unsure where I am going wrong?

Comment: It doesn't appear to be a problem with the folder path. But if it was, you could easily check it by seeing if you have any 404 errors in the `Network` tab of your browser.

Comment: Has this been resolved? If so, and any of the answers were helpful to you, please mark one of them as "Accepted". Otherwise, if you'd like some more clarification or still having an issue, just say so.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem seems to be that `@font-face` is not supposed to be put into a CSS selector. Instead, `@font-face` stands by itself, and you use it with `font-family`.

This is how it should be used:

```
@font-face{
    font-family: fishes;
    src: url(/path/to/file);
    font-weight: 400;
}

h1{
    font-family:fishes;
}
```

**But**, your code appears to be incorrectly compiling into this:

```
h1{
    @font-face{
        font-family: fishes;
        src: url(/path/to/file);
        font-weight: 400;
    }
}
```

Which is invalid CSS.

Instead, you should probably do something like this:

```
//Beginning of CSS file.
@include font-face("lemonmilk", "/assets/build/fonts/lemon-milk/bold/lemonmilk-bold", $style: normal, $weight: normal);

...
...
...

h1{
    font-family:lemonmilk;
    font-weight:normal;
}
```

and delete the `@mixin lemonmilk-bold`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be more simple than you think. Font face declarations need to appear on the page before any other CSS selector.

Like this:

```
@font-face{
  font-family: 'Your Font;;
  src: url(/var/fonts/yourfont.woff);
  font-weight: 500;
}

body{
  margin: 0;
}

/* more CSS code */
```

Not this:

```
/* Code before the font face declaration */
body{
  margin: 0;
}

@font-face{
  font-family: 'Your Font;;
  src: url(/var/fonts/yourfont.woff);
  font-weight: 500;
}

/* more CSS code */
```